# View height reduce

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, autolayout, autoresizingmask

I have used one `view controller` in my project.

In `viewDidLoad` method when I log frame size of view I got 568 but when I log it in `viewDidAppear` it is 480.

I am disaplying one tbaleview and toolbar in view. I have uncheck autolayout and also uncheck bottom autoresizingmask.Why this is happening?

When I test it in iphone5 simulator it is showing 568 both time and when I test it in iphone4 simulator it is showing 480 in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: And what's your question ?

Comment: is your `viewcontroller` is childviewcontroller(subview) of any other ViewController.?

Comment: Which version of X-Code are you using?

Comment: xcode-5.....@footyapps27

Answer (score 0):

The sooner you'll get the correct size of a viewcontroller's view on creation is on the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, so you should probably do all your positioning there.